# Unexpected token ) fault JS code cant find the error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I keep receiving the error **unexpected token ")"** in the following code. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
function postFrom()
{
 /* contactform */
$.post('/contact_owner/send/', { 

customer_name: $('[name="customer_name"]').val(),
customer_phone: $('[name="customer_phone"]').val(),
customer_email: $('[name="customer_email"]').val(),

customer_message: $('[name="customer_message"]').val() +' \n-Adress: '+ $('[name="customer_address"]').val() +' -Postnummer: '+ $('[name="customer_zipcode"]').val() +' -Ort: '+ $('[name="customer_city"]').val() + ' -Markisvävar: '+ final,

subject:$('[name="customer_name"]').val() +' - '+ $('[name="sub"]').val()  },     function(data){
  if (data) {
    $('#status_notice').css('color', 'red');
    $('#status_notice').html(data);
  } else {
    $('#status_notice').css('color', 'green');
    $('#status_notice').html('Ditt meddelande skickades.');
    $('[name="customer_name"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_phone"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_email"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_address"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_zipcode"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_city"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_message"]').val('');
  $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() 
  { 
    this.checked = false; 
  }); 

}
});
event.preventDefault();
});
});                                                       

/* contactform END */

}//end function
```

Comment: what line does it say its happening on?

Comment: line after event.preventDefault();

Comment: You would make it yourself a lot easier to just start to properly indent your code.

Comment: Run your code through http://jsbeautifier.org/ and then lint it at http://www.jshint.com/.

Comment: @FelixKling Why so complicated when you can use jsFiddle there is tidyup and jshint

Comment: @Givi: I personally find the JSHint support in jsFiddle not that great, but apart from that, the more tools you have in your belt, the better. Plus, it was easier to write than explain to click on this button and then that button and then look for tiny red dots next to the line numbers ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use `}):` to close the function (you need to just use `}`), also you have some stray closing brackets.

**Try this:**

```
function postFrom()
{
 /* contactform */
$.post('/contact_owner/send/', { 

  customer_name: $('[name="customer_name"]').val(),
  customer_phone: $('[name="customer_phone"]').val(),
  customer_email: $('[name="customer_email"]').val(),

  customer_message: $('[name="customer_message"]').val() +' \n-Adress: '+ $('[name="customer_address"]').val() +' -Postnummer: '+ $('[name="customer_zipcode"]').val() +' -Ort: '+ $('[name="customer_city"]').val() + ' -Markisvävar: '+ final,

  subject:$('[name="customer_name"]').val() +' - '+ $('[name="sub"]').val()  },     function(data){
  if (data) {
    $('#status_notice').css('color', 'red');
    $('#status_notice').html(data);
  } else {
    $('#status_notice').css('color', 'green');
    $('#status_notice').html('Ditt meddelande skickades.');
    $('[name="customer_name"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_phone"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_email"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_address"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_zipcode"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_city"]').val('');
    $('[name="customer_message"]').val('');
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function() 
  { 
    this.checked = false; 
}); 

}
});
event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it! Im accepting ur answer as you were the first to provide the solution.

Answer (score 4):

After formatting the code, it appears that the last two `});` lines are extraneous, and should be removed.

After formatting:

```
function postFrom()
{
    /* contactform */
    $.post('/contact_owner/send/', {
        customer_name: $('[name="customer_name"]').val(),
        customer_phone: $('[name="customer_phone"]').val(),
        customer_email: $('[name="customer_email"]').val(),
        customer_message: $('[name="customer_message"]').val() + ' \n-Adress: ' + $('[name="customer_address"]').val() + ' -Postnummer: ' + $('[name="customer_zipcode"]').val() + ' -Ort: ' + $('[name="customer_city"]').val() + ' -Markisvävar: ' + final,
        subject: $('[name="customer_name"]').val() + ' - ' + $('[name="sub"]').val()}, function(data) {
        if (data) {
            $('#status_notice').css('color', 'red');
            $('#status_notice').html(data);
        } else {
            $('#status_notice').css('color', 'green');
            $('#status_notice').html('Ditt meddelande skickades.');
            $('[name="customer_name"]').val('');
            $('[name="customer_phone"]').val('');
            $('[name="customer_email"]').val('');
            $('[name="customer_address"]').val('');
            $('[name="customer_zipcode"]').val('');
            $('[name="customer_city"]').val('');
            $('[name="customer_message"]').val('');
            $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function()
            {
                this.checked = false;
            });
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
    /* contactform END */

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Typo error, extra brackets

```
});
event.preventDefault();
}); // delete it
}); // delete it
```

Answer (score 2):

Better indentation would probably help you a lot, but I think both the }); lines (33, 34) aren't needed assuming the event.PreventDefault should be at the end of the function.